# componentDidMount() not waiting to get new object before render?

Tags: react-native

Code - http://pastebin.com/skU2zdFd

---

The listview is being created from the initial set bankrolldata but I need it to wait for the new object.
How can I get the listview to update with the new data?

The componentDidMount() should surely wait for the function to finish?

Thanks

I am new and learning so please offer as much insight as you can!

Comment: Please post code here (but having a pastebin link too is ok). Otherwise if the pastebin link stops working or changes in the future the post will not make sense to readers.

Comment: componentDidMount won't wait for async operations, just like normal JS doesn't wait. Can you post more code? And what specific error are you getting? If it's something along the lines of 'x is undefined' then use getInitialState to establish the initial state of your component before your async calls finish.

Answer (score 1):

React-native is based on JS, which means that it doesn't wait for async operations.

What you can do is render a loading screen and change a state once the files have loaded by your async function.